# Row number with len in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to take the length of a specific row and show this substring, but I'm not getting luck, can somebody help me I was trying something like this:

```
declare @teste int
declare @rows int

select @rows = (select COUNT(DS_Description) from IMPL_Activities)

while @rows > 0
begin 
    --select @test = (select LEN(DS_Description), ROW_NUMBER() over (order by  ID_Deployment) rn 
    --from IMPL_Activities where rn in (@rows))
    select 
        @test = (select * 
                 from 
                     (select 
                          ROW_NUMBER() over(order by ID_Deployment) rn 
                      from IMPL_Activities) as imp 
                 where rn in (@rows) 
    select LEN(DS_Description) from IMPL_Activities where rn in (@rows))

    set @rows = @rows - 1

    select SUBSTRING(DS_Description, 1, @test) 
    from IMPL_Activities 
end
```

But can't save the number of character that have this column in that row, I don't know if did you understood, but comments, or edit, to make sure that everyone will understand.

Thanks

Comment: As posted this doesn't have anywhere near enough detail. What table? What about some sample data? Given a certain value what should be the output and why? Give us something to work with here.

Comment: The value output, is the middle character of every row of the column "DS_description"

Comment: You have to remember I can't see your screen, I don't know your table structures and have no idea what you are trying to do. What does row number have to do with anything and why are you using a cursor? How do you define "middle character" when there are an even number of characters? If the string is 10 character do you want 5 or 6? The are both in the middle since character 5.5 doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you elaborate?   can you provide sample input and output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No cursor necessary, is this what you want?

```
SELECT 
   SUBSTRING(DS_Description,LEN(DS_Description)/2,1) 
FROM 
   IMPL_Activities;
```

Comment: Select the lines of code you want as a code block and then click the curly braces button {}.

Comment: +1 - That is pretty much what I was guessing myself. No clue if that is what they really want or not yet. :)

Comment: Don't sweat it. The UI for answers leaves a bit to be desired imho.

Comment: Wonder if it's my version of Chrome?  Why doesn't anyone else have the same issue.  I searched for it and saw a few references but it didn't seem popular